# Usb card is not recognized by ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, mount, partitioning

On my laptop with the system Ubuntu 16.04, the mini-cd card is not recognized by the system. I tried almost all the solutions that I found on the net but they didn't work.
I reinstalled *gpart*, *udisk2*...

Comment: What size? No problems with anything <=32GB, but 64GB and bigger don't work in 16.04 and AFAIK there is no fix in 16.04.

Comment: Yeah it was 64 gb. Thank you for the reply. ))